# Como utilizar um script para várias páginas sem dar o erro do eventListener no console?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos, eventos, event-listener

Segue um exemplo simples pra demonstrar a dúvida. São duas páginas e um script. Sei que funciona importando o script nas duas páginas, porém quando utilizo o `eventListener`, ele mostra o erro dizendo que não encontrou o elemento alvo da página que não foi carregada. Apesar de nesse exemplo mais simples funcionar, a mensagem de erro fica aparecendo no console, e em exemplos mais complexos o evento para de funcionar.

Mensagem de erro:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Página 1:

```
<body>
  <button id="botao1">botão 1</button>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Página 2:

```
<body>
  <button id="botao2">botão 2</button>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
let botao1 = document.getElementById("botao1");
let botao2 = document.getElementById("botao2");

botao1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("botao 1");
});

botao2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("botao 2");
});
```

Comment: Que tal fazer um simples `if`? Ou separar os scripts? Ou colocar o JS diretamente em uma tag `script`?

Comment: Então, esse foi um exemplo, mas o projeto que estou fazendo tem um script de 87 linhas, não seria uma boa prática colocar ele em cada html. A opção ideal realmente seria separar os scripts, mas gostaria de saber se é possível resolver essa questão da forma que eu deixei aí. Como o "if" resolveria essa questão?

Comment: E validar que o botão existe?

if(typeof(botao1) != 'undefined' && botao1  != null){
        alert('Botão existe!');
  botao1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert("botao 1");
  });
    } else{
        alert('Botão não existe!');
    }

Comment: Entendi, obrigado :)

Comment: Mas o código para ambos os botões é o mesmo ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tente para o JS:

```
botaoex.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("botao ex");
});
```

Deixe o mesmo id em ambas as páginas.

Comment: É uma opção. Obrigado :)